# Changing variable value dynamically with angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to learn angularjs.

I have the following controller,

```
   skillPopulator.controller('skillsetController', function(){
         this.skillType = language; //value to be changed
    });
```

`language` and `database` are jsons in custom.js within the wrapper where controller is present like

```
var language = {         
            name: 'Java, Javascript, HTML5, CSS3'
        }
var database = {         
            name: 'MySQL, Oracle, PostGres'
        }
```

I would like to change the value of `skillType` to `database` upon the event

```
$("#db-skill").hover();
```

1) If I do so, will the change get reflected on my {{skill.skillType.name}} without a refresh?

2) How would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use your variables at html side you should add them to `$scope`, so your basic jsons in controller like this has no meaning at html side, that is why you see no changes when you over your html item...

change your jsons to this...

```
$scope.language = {         
            name: 'Java, Javascript, HTML5, CSS3'
        }
$scope.database = {         
            name: 'MySQL, Oracle, PostGres'
        }
```

and here is a working [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/E0X1ZIo0Gr7hsulrwqnK?p=preview)...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-mouseover`
See docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover

Instead of using this

```
$("#db-skill").hover();
```

use this:

```
<ANY id="db-skill" ng-mouseover="skillType = database"></ANY>
```

Comment: When I do that, it removes the current value. But it does not update it with the 'database.name' value. As if it is not able to find the json variable 'database'

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr or fiddle?